# How to get pagesource of particular part of a webpage in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get pagesource of a specific part of the page. As we now that driver.getPageSource() will returns the entire source of the page.

My concern is - Is there any way to get HTML content between two web elements?

Comment: do you mean the content between two HTML tags? what do you mean web elements exactly

Comment: Yes. I mean the same. Content in the sence, including tags as well.

Comment: Though not exactly correct, one close answer is that, find one webelement, and retrieve its parent HTML using .getAttribute('outerHTML') on that WebElement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got some progress. @Naveen

Is it possible to get only the content by excluding tags?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. I suggest using language built-in libraries, like `String.split` or `regex based matching` etc.

Comment: This helped me.
Jsoup.parse(htmlString).text() which will return plaintext without any tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get some part of html by using the below method

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathOfParentElement)).getAttribute("outerHTML");
```

Later, I parsed the htmlString in the below method

```
org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(htmlString).text();
```

Maven Dependency :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```